# How to hide navigation bar on a particular view controller inside of navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistatusbar

I have 8 view controllers embedded into 1 navigation controller. I'd like to hide the navigation bar  (keeping status bar) on my first view controller. When I've tried to do this this, the navigation bar disappears on all my view controllers.

Comment: It would be helpful to tell how did you do that, add some code, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in the first view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: This does work - however all my objects on storyboard have been moved up the screen at runtime.

Comment: @lbudge What do you mean? Could you provide screenshot?